# uninitialized constant Arel::SqlLiteral in upgrade to rails 4.2

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

In the process of upgrading to rails 4.2. Actually upgrading from 3.2-stable but have gone one step at a time. Was able to run the app without any trouble (after changes) on rails 4.1.

Upon upgrading to 4.2, though, I ran into this error:

```
uninitialized constant Arel::SqlLiteral
```

Having trouble finding any information about it. There were some posts about geokit...which we don't use. Anyone have any thoughts about this error and what it means? Better yet--any advice about how to go about debugging it? We use mysql for our db.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I get the same thing when I look between my rails 4.2 and rails 3.x projects. You may have to change your references to Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral

```
irb(main):002:0> Arel::SqlLiteral
NameError: uninitialized constant Arel::SqlLiteral

irb(main):003:0> Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral
=> Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral
```